# out of memory loading several image view

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a viewpager and need to inflate in it a layout containing images and I have 73 image and I am loading them from pics[] an int array list, so while swiping the viewpager to see these images I am getting on the 7th image out of memory exception my code is:

```
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);      
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_view_layout, null);
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.img_view = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_pager);
            //img_v=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img_pager);
            int count=NUM_VIEWS-1;
            view.setTag(holder);
            holder.img_view.setImageResource(pics[count-position]);         

            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

            return view;
        }
```

Comment: How large are these images?

Comment: dimensions:634x700  size:140KB not that large;

Comment: Are you preloading all 73?

Comment: plus am i using the viewholder correctly cz found no difference with it and without it...

Comment: @EmilDavtyan what do you mean by preloading? I've already written my code, please check it, what I know is that the viewpager loads each 2 items at the same time right?

Comment: @User Where is `pics` instantiated?

Comment: outside the methods at the begining of the class private int[] pics = {R.drawable.intro1, R.drawable.intro2,...}

Answer (score 0):

You should follow these guidelines : 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

To display images efficiently follow these instructions , it will avoid out of memory exceptions

Answer (score 0):

First off all you are using `ViewPager` incorrectly, set it up and pass it a listener to [`setOnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOnPageChangeListener%28android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener%29) then when pages change, change the image view.

Then in your page listener, define [`onPageSelected`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageSelected%28int%29) to take the position and load the image and set it as the resource for the `ImageView`.

Don't preload all 73 images even at 140KB each that is over 10MB, add that to the rest of overhead of running the app you can easily go over the 16MB limit on older phones. Figure out a smarter way to preload, maybe just the keep the previous and next image cached, or look into this [lazy loading library](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

Comment: I am sorry but why I am using the viewpager in a wrong way? if I placed the holder.img_view.setImageResource(pics[count-position]); in the onpagestatechanged() the app doesn't even load sorry but it's my first app and I am still learning...

Comment: @User You should not be using the `addView` on the `ViewPager` to add the images. The pager is only there to catch page flips and give you notice of them, you then alter the layout accordingly.

Comment: @User You should look over this tutorial on how to use it with a page adapter, the solution I proposed was simpler. But this should be a good explanation : http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Answer (score 0):

I had to add:

android:largeHeap="true"

to my app manifest!!

Comment: You should not add this unless you're absolutely sure where your memory is getting used, which objects, and you absolutely have to have them. This would cause the heap size to increase, that would case the GC to kick in more frequently and therefore increase pause times. Check this Google IO talk on [Memory Management by Patrick Dubroy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk).